# 'AuthenticationManager' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, error

I have the following code to connect to SharePoint using clientID and ClientSecret:

```
string siteUrl = "https://****l.sharepoint.com/sites/DocumentApprovalProcess/";
string clientId = "***";
string clientSecret = "**";

using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
```

But I am getting this error:

> 'AuthenticationManager' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Which version of SharePoint and CSOM are you using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am using sharepoint online and CSOM version 16.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is in OfficeDevPnP.Core. You need to install OfficeDevPnP.Core.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.authenticationmanager.getapponlyauthenticatedcontext

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-online-site-with-app-only-authentication/